# ListView only show 1 item

Tags: android, listview, show

I have layout with this sequence : imageview, ratingbar, and tabhost (contains review of user and info). For tabhost review of user, I am using custom listview, and I was successfully to display all of reviews from user. But my problem, you can see below image (listview height is wrap content only for 1 item, if i scroll it, it can load all data)

http://pbrd.co/1wctFFz

And this one layout that I want to make (it display multiple item as parent's height)

http://pbrd.co/1wctBFZ

Here my layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#dcdcdc"
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ivplacedetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/search"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" />   
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />     

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#a9d633">
        <Button 
           android:id="@+id/btnhome"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
           android:text="Home"
           android:background="@layout/round_border"/>          
        <Button 
           android:id="@+id/btnbookmark"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
           android:text="Bookmark"
           android:background="@layout/round_border"/>  
        <Button 
           android:id="@+id/btnnearby"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
           android:text="Nearby"
           android:background="@layout/round_border"/>             
    </LinearLayout>     
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header">     
        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

            </LinearLayout> 
        </TabHost>                          
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my listview custom layout here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/imguser" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="1dp"
         android:src="@drawable/atmicon"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"> 
     </ImageView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lbluser" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imguser"
        android:textColor="#4068ec"
        android:text="Nama User"> 
    </TextView> 
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lblwaktu" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imguser"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbluser"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:text="Waktu Review">
    </TextView> 
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lblreview" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imguser"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblwaktu"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:text="isi Review">        
    </TextView>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

my listview layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvreview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can somebody help me to fix my layout ?

Comment: when you log it in the adapter what value do you get 10 or 1..the problem might be that the adapter is populated before the loop completes

Comment: All of the data(review) is already displayed, but the problem now is it's height is only for 1 data(review) as the link show

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare your adapter in your main class

```
private ListViewReviewAdapter reviewAdapter;
```

Second of all first init your adapter then add data to it, even if arruserreview is empty

```
reviewAdapter = new ListViewReviewAdapter(getBaseContext(), arruserreview);
lvreview.setAdapter(reviewAdapter);
```

In your for loop do the following :

```
for (int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    UserReviewClass userreview=new UserReviewClass(String.valueOf(i),"Budi"+String.valueOf(i),"10/19/2014","Tempatnya lumayan. Pelayanan yang diberikan baik");
    arruserreview.add(userreview);
    reviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

So you'll have something like this :

```
ArrayList<UserReviewClass> arruserreview = new ArrayList<UserReviewClass>();
ListView lvreview ;
private ListViewReviewAdapter reviewAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_review);

    lvreview     = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvreview);
    reviewAdapter = new ListViewReviewAdapter(getBaseContext(), arruserreview);
    lvreview.setAdapter(reviewAdapter);

    for (int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        UserReviewClass userreview=new UserReviewClass(String.valueOf(i),"Budi"+String.valueOf(i),"10/19/2014","Tempatnya lumayan. Pelayanan yang diberikan baik");
        arruserreview.add(userreview);
        reviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Comment: Initializing and setting the array adapter before the array is known is not necessary, neither is notifyDataSetChanged() while executing the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel M mentioned, declare your adapter (it's just good practice for a variety of reasons).

```
private ListViewReviewAdapter reviewAdapter;
```

Once arruserreview array is constructed in your for-loop, pass the array to your adapter and set it:

```
reviewAdapter = new ListViewReviewAdapter(this, arruserreview);
lvreview.setAdapter(reviewAdapter);
```

In your array adapter, change your constructor to:

```
public ListViewReviewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UserReviewClass> results) {
    DataProcessorResult = results;
    mycontext = context;
    myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

Since you're passing context as a parameter in your reviewAdapter and to your constructor, you can remove the following line from your adapter class:

```
final Context mycontext=parent.getContext();
```